# Dataflow WordCount stuck

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am running the WordCount example from the DataflowJavaSDK-Examples folder.

```
mvn compile exec:java -exec.mainClass=com.google.cloud.dataflow.examples.WordCount -Dexec.args="--project=<YOUR CLOUD PLATFORM PROJECT ID> --stagingLocation=<YOUR CLOUD STORAGE LOCATION> --runner=BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner --inputFile=gs://df1/L1.txt --output=gs://df1"
```

I am getting the following.  It is running for 20 mins now.

Oct 12, 2015 9:32:36 AM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineJo
b getJobWithRetries

> WARNING: There were problems getting current job status: 429 Too Many Requests

```
{  
  "code" : 429,  
  "errors" : [ {  
    "domain" : "global",  
    "message" : "Request throttled due to project QPS limit being reached.",  
    "reason" : "rateLimitExceeded"  
  } ],  
  "message" : "Request throttled due to project QPS limit being reached.",  
  "status" : "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"  
}.
```

Comment: Are you using your actual project id, to replace "<YOUR CLOUD PLATFORM PROJECT ID>" ?

Comment: yes, I am using the actual projectid.

Answer (score 1):

That suggests a problem polling for the job status in the BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner, which won't affect job execution. You should be able to verify the state of the job in either the [monitoring UI](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/dataflow-monitoring-intf) or the [CLI](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/dataflow-command-line-intf). As for why you hit this, were you trying to monitor multiple jobs at the same time?

Comment: No, I was not trying to monitor mutiple jobs.  I was exploring the WordCount example.

Comment: How long will it take to run the default WordCount example on the Google Dataflow service.  It is about 1hr, and it is still doing.

Comment: That's unexpected. Should be ~3 minutes. Can you provide the job id?

Comment: It is '2015-10-11_22_41_07-11411764987356154659'.  I cancelled the job after 1hr.

Comment: We see almost no traces of worker activity by this job in our logs. Seems like perhaps there was something wrong with the worker setup. Could you take a look at the worker logs of this job in Cloud Logging and contact dataflow-feedback@google.com with the details?

Comment: I have submitted more information, although logs is very difficult to provide.  It has lot of json content, which makes it difficult to do cut & paste